# Positioning Divs in Container

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to layout a page, but I am having trouble getting my divs to work as I want.

This is how my page is showing up

[image: My page]

But I want all the textual content to be pushed to the right, with the 'Session attended:' being next to the avatar, and no text at all underneath where the avatar is. Like there are two boxes, one small skinny one the width of the avatar and height of the entire container, and one larger the width of the textual content and the height of the container.

Here is my HTML...

```
<div class="well row">

        <div style="height: 100%; float: left;">
            <img class="review-img" src="src" alt="Thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="review">
            <strong>Session attended: </strong>All about the Box...ing<br>
            <p style="padding-top: 8px;">Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes. Gumby likes.</p>
            <span>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
                     Gumby  
                    <strong class="recommended"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Recommends</strong>
                    10/27/2014
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

with this CSS

```
.review {
    float: left;
}

.review-img {
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.review {
    padding: 8px;
}

.review span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 12px;
}
```

I am using Bootstrap, if that isn't obvious from the above materials. I feel like this should be easy, as it is essentially just defining 2 containers inside the greater container and floating them both left, but for some reason it's giving me trouble.

**EDIT**

Here is a jsfiddle with my code http://jsfiddle.net/ta37frf3/

Comment: Don't put lot of code here this will definitely decrease any one's interest to answer please make a jsfiddle out of it and provide the link :) !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove `float` from the review and give some margin to parent.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ta37frf3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you aren't familiar with [Bootstrap's grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). As a summary, after you create a row, you'll need to use the `col-screensize-columnsize` on the inner elements in order to create responsive columns on the page. You can remove your CSS and use this instead:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <img class="review-img" src="src" alt="Thumbnail">
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <!-- all your text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap is a really powerful CSS framework and you should always consult the documentation to see if what you're trying to accomplish has already been implemented in Bootstrap.

NOTE: I'm assuming you're using the latest version of Bootstrap, Bootstrap 3.

Comment: I am familiar with the grid system, but I did not want the thumbnail to be placed above the text at smaller screen sizes, as would happen using the bootstrap grid.

Comment: Then you aren't using it right. You should be using `xs` instead of `md` then. Read up on the docs. Also, that's information you should have provided in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this, you should get what I understood you wanted :

```
.review {
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT**

To be closer, you can encapsulate the sentence that you want on side on the image, and thus remove `<br>` as well as `padding-top` on the next element. Then you can target it to adjust it's height and margins.

(I replaced the img with a colored div so we can see it well)

**EDIT 2**

I added the `padding-top` again and cleared the text box so it never get on the image.

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ta37frf3/6/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.review {
    padding: 8px;
    width:70%;
    box-sizing: padding;
}
```

instead 100% width give 30% to the div

```
<div style="height: 30%; float: left;">
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9qx109t/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to give the avatar its own `<div class="avatar">` then float it left in your css. Also your comment too will be `<div class="comment">` would float right. Remember to clear both so the next items can sit in normally.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you use Bootstrap 3, you can use media object component built-in Bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" src="review-img" alt="thumbnail">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <strong>Session attended: </strong>All about the Box...ing
    </div>
</div>
```